# Match string rstudio

Tags: r

I have this column in my dataframe

```
df[column] = 10$ , 20eur, 10eur, 8$......
```

I would like to get with Rstudio take the numbers with "eur" and change to $. Then this change , remove the $ and eur strings. I tried with str_extract but this doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: See `?sub`. Note also that the correct tag should be `r`, not `rstudio` which is unrelated to this question.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I change the tag. Thanks!

Comment: Since you are using `stringr` you could use `str_replace(x, 'eur', '$')`. See `help(str_replace)` for details. This is similar to `gsub`.

Comment: do you want to convert euros in dollars with a fixed ratio? Or just extract the numbers?

Comment: great question from edo. If you want to actually convert eur to usd, you could use something like `rows <- grepl(df$column, 'eur$'); values <- as.numeric(gsub('eur', '', df[rows, column]); df[rows, column] <- paste(round(values * 1.18, 0), '$')`. That assumes a EURUSD FX rate of 1.18.The first part finds the rows ending with 'eur', then we remove eur, and change it to a numeric value. Last we multiply by the EURUSD exchange rate, and round it to a full value (`round(x, 0)`), and use `paste` to add a dollar sign at the end.

Comment: the change is 1$ = 0.80€ it is fixed ratio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your input:

```
df <- data.frame(column = c("10$", "20eur", "10eur", "8$", "100.5eur"))
```

You can do the following:

```
library(stringr)

# extract numbers
df$value <- as.numeric(str_extract(df$column, "^\\d+(\\.\\d*)?"))

# extract the currency
df$currency <- str_remove_all(df$column, "^\\d+(\\.\\d*)?")

# convert with a fixed ratio when necessary
ratio <- 1.25 # 1$ = 0.8eur ==> 1eur = 1.25$
df$converted_value <- ifelse(df$currency == "eur", df$value * ratio, df$value)

df
#>     column value currency converted_value
#> 1      10$  10.0        $          10.000
#> 2    20eur  20.0      eur          25.000
#> 3    10eur  10.0      eur          12.500
#> 4       8$   8.0        $           8.000
#> 5 100.5eur 100.5      eur         125.625
```

---

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
 mutate(value = as.numeric(str_extract(column, "^\\d+(\\.\\d*)?")),
        currency = str_remove_all(column, "^\\d+(\\.\\d*)?")) %>% 
 mutate(converted_value = if_else(currency == "eur", value * ratio, value))
```

---

Here a brief explanation how to read this:

```
"^\\d+(\\.\\d*)?"
```

This is a way to read decimal numbers with a regex.

- `^` stands for the beginning of the string. It means you're looking for something that begins with what follows `^`
- `\d` stands for digits. You need double `\\` to "escape" it, because `\` is a special character and you can't write on its own in most of R regeces.
- `(...)?` means that the content of the parentheses may or may not be there.
- `\\.` is the decimal point. `.` is a special character in a regex: it may stand for any character. Therefore, if you actually mean `.`, you need to "escape" it [twice, coz again `\` is a special character as well].
- `\\d+` means that there may be one or more digits, while `\\d*` means that there may be zero or more digits.

Comment: if I have a float number like 100.5eur? I can't use it

Comment: Where could I see all the parttern? like "^\\d+\\.?\\d*" because I don't know all the combinations but it is very helpful

Comment: check out `?base::regex`

Comment: is the answer what you were looking for?

Comment: ok! and could you explain to me the one you used it? Because I would like to understand . Thank you!!

Comment: Yes! this is the answer!!

Comment: I added an explanation of the regex :)